# Why aren't reputation lines grouped?

Tags: support, bug

Please see following image,
[image]

Both the reputation refer to exact same question. But I see 2 rows, instead of them grouped together. Is it a bug? or am I missing something?

**Edit:**

I saw it again and it got grouped. :| So, Is there a lag in grouping logic?

Comment: Because you filter by time, not post. Click the "post" link in the top right and it will all be grouped.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It was filtered by `post` earlier. Now, also, it is filtered by `post`. Now they are grouped. Is it because of some delay in grouping?

Comment: I have not seen any formal statement if this is a real-bug and/or it's cause. I blame caching.

Comment: @rene I don't think it was caching. As I refreshed page multiple times. Anyways, I guess the question was answered previously. Thanks for pointing it out  :)

Comment: It might also be a script that needs to run to do the proper grouping. It might gather events first and simply send them to the profile. After the script has run all events are taken into account and properly grouped. Only a dev can confirm or deny...